# Loading csv - One row of intergers

Tags: r

Problem reading data vector - My csv data file (rab.csv) has just one row of > 10,000 numbers read into R with:

```
bab <- read.table("rab.csv")  #which yields:
bab
V1
1 23,29,9,28,16,10,8,24,16,20,14,15,17,31,25,19,24,55,28,55,23, . . . and so on
```

In using this data vector, I get:

> Error: data vector must consist of at least two distinct values!

It seems to only see the number `"1"` that was somehow added in front of the data.

I'm quite new to this so probably something simple, but I've spent 2 days searching every possibility I can think of without finding a solution.

Comment: You can use `scan("rab.csv", what=numeric(), sep=",")` to read the data as a `vector`.  With the `read.table`, if you don't specify the `header=FALSE`, it will include the first row as a header and as it is all numeric, it adds `X` based on the `make.names`

Comment: That worked brilliantly!  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scan` to read the file as a `vector`.

```
 v1 <- scan("rab.csv", what=numeric(), sep=",")
```

In the `read.table`, if we don't specify `header=FALSE`, it will take the first column as `header` and as it is numeric, it will append `X` as prefix.  (though, it can be avoided by using `check.names=FALSE` argument)